# need help creating Jpeg Generational Degradation code

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, jpeg, opencv

I am currently creating a [Generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) code for `.jpeg` images.

**Theory:-** `.jpg` is a lossy compression format (for the most part). i.e. every time the image is converted to `.jpg` some contents/data of the original image is lost in the process. This results in lower file sizes, but due to the loss of data the image is of lower quality then the original. In most use cases, the degradation in quality is negligible. But if this process is carried out a lot of time, all the pixel data of the image get's compressed (lost) so many times, that we end up with just random noise.

I have tried doing it on `PIL` and `cv2`, but had no success.

**What i tried:-** Opening the image (let's say a image of format `.png`), and converting it into a `.jpg`. Then converting the image (which is currently of format `.jpg`) back to `.png`, so that the before mentioned process can be carried out several times.

My reasoning behind this is, since we are converting the original image into a jpeg, some data should be lost.

I am displaying the image using `cv2.imshow()` because the window stays active until destroyed explicitly, or an `cv2.destroyWindow()`/`cv2.destroyAllWindows()` is encountered.

I expected the image to show up, and its quality to gradually decrease as the program goes by, but for some reason the image  stays the same. So, I am expecting someone to help me create the code from scratch (as my current efforts are in vain).

**P.S.:-** The Reason why I didn't posted any code, is because it's more of a bodge rather then anything concrete, and does nothing towards achieving the objective. So me uploading it would only waste, others time analysing it.

Comment: The YouTube video you link to doesn't appear (to me at least) to show *"generational loss"*. I think it shows what happens when you save the same image at `quality=100`, then at `quality=99` then at `quality=98`. To my mind, it is comparing loss at one quality versus loss at a different quality. I understand *"generational loss"* to be loss of quality caused by repeated saving at some fixed quality.

Comment: @MarkSetchell You could possibly be right, as I have never done it myself, neither seen a working example of it. So I just searched it on the internet, and found that video (without confirming its working), as i thought it closely resembled what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The flaw in your theory is here:

> every time the image is converted to .jpg some contents/data of the original image is lost in the process.

If you have already converted to JPEG and recompress with the same settings you might not loose data.

Comment: What I did is, Opened a `.png` image, saved it as a `.jpg`, then open the saved `.jpg` and save it as a `.png` (so that this process could be repeated). Is this  equivalent of what you stated?

Comment: Unless you change the JPEG settings each time, that should not continuously degrade your image.