# Why JPEG compressing an uncompressed image differs its original (FFmpeg, NvJPEG, ...)

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, jpeg, nvidia, yuv

I am currently struggling to understand why recompressing an uncompressed JPEG image differs its original.

It's clear, that JPEG is a lossy compression, but what if the image to compress is already uncompressed, which means all sampling losses are already included? In other words: Downsampling and DCT should be inversable at this point without loosing data.

[image: JPEG algorithm]

To make sure losses are not effected by the color space conversion, this step is skipped and YUV images are used.

1. Compress YUV image to JPEG (*image.yuv* --> *image.yuv.jpg*)
2. Uncompress JPEG image to YUV image (*image.yuv.jpg* --> *image.yuv.jpg.yuv*)
3. Compress YUV image to JPEG (*image.yuv.jpg.yuv* --> *image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg*)
4. Uncompress JPEG image to YUV image (*image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg* --> *image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg.yuv*)

Step 1 includes a lossy compression, so we will not deal with this step anymore. For me, intresting is what happens afterwards:

Uncompressing the JPEG image back to YUV (step 2) leads to an image which perfectly fits all sampling steps if compressed again (step 3). So the JPEG image after step 3 should (from my understanding) be exactly the same as after step 1. Also the YUV images after step 4 and step 2 should equal each other.

Looking at the steps for one 8x8 block the following simplified sequence should illustrate what I am trying to descibe. Lets start with the original YUV image, which can only be decompressed loosing all decimal places:

```
[ 1.123, 2.345, 3.456, ... ]    (YUV)
    DTC + Quantization
[ -26, -3, -6, ... ]            (Quantized frequency space)
    Inverse DTC + Quantization
[ 1, 2, 3, ... ]                (YUV)
```

Doing this with input, which already matches all steps, which may lead to loss of data afterwards (using round numbers in my example), the decompressed image should match its original:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, ... ]                (YUV)
    DTC + Quantization
[ -26, -3, -6, ... ]            (Quantized frequency space)
    Inverse DTC + Quantization
[ 1, 2, 3, ... ]                (YUV)
```

There are also some sources and discussions, which are confirming my idea:

- [need help creating Jpeg Generational Degradation code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021093/need-help-creating-jpeg-generational-degradation-code/57028812#57028812)
- [What factors cause or prevent “generational loss” when JPEGs are recompressed multiple times?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/99604/what-factors-cause-or-prevent-generational-loss-when-jpegs-are-recompressed-mu)
- [Lossless Chroma Subampling](https://forum.shotcut.org/t/lossless-chroma-subampling/5760)

So much for theory. In praxis, I've runned these steps using ffmpeg and [Nvidias jpeg samples](https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/l4t-multimedia/l4t_mm_jpeg_encode.html) (using [NvJPEGEncoder](https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/l4t-multimedia/classNvJPEGEncoder.html)).

**ffmpeg:**

```
#Create YUV image
ffmpeg -y -i image.jpg -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p image.yuv
#YUV to JPEG
ffmpeg -y -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i image.yuv image.yuv.jpg
#JPEG TO YUV
ffmpeg -y -i image.yuv.jpg -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p image.yuv.jpg.yuv
#YUV to JPEG
ffmpeg -y -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i image.yuv.jpg.yuv image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg
#JPEG TO YUV
ffmpeg -y -i image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg.yuv
#YUV to JPEG
ffmpeg -y -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg.yuv image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg
```

**Nvidia:**

```
#Create YUV image
./jpeg_decode num_files 1 image.jpg image.yuv
#YUV to JPEG
./jpeg_encode image.yuv 1920 1080 image.yuv.jpg
#JPEG TO YUV
./jpeg_decode num_files 1 image.yuv.jpg image.yuv.jpg.yuv
#YUV to JPEG
./jpeg_encode image.yuv.jpg.yuv 1920 1080 image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg
#JPEG TO YUV
./jpeg_decode num_files 1 image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg.yuv
#YUV to JPEG
./jpeg_encode image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg.yuv 1920 1080 image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg
```

But a comparison of the images

- *image.yuv.jpg.yuv* and *image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg.yuv*
- *image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg* and *image.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg.yuv.jpg*

showing differences in the files. That brings me to my question **why and where the difference gets happen**, since from my understanding the files should be equal.

Comment: When compressing in JPEG format, a certain amount of information is thrown away. Each compression step will throw away some information. Using lossless JPEG the 2nd time *might* produce the same JPEG stream as your 1st time, but I’m not sure this is necessarily the case.

Comment: You may be right @CrisLuengo - but where and why? I've added a simplified example to my question, which may help you to give me some detailed hints here?

Comment: Lossy compression involves setting DCT components to 0. The higher the compression ratio, the more components are dropped.

Comment: Dropping components by setting them to 0 should not make a difference than dropping decimal places in my example. So I don't think this is the reason.

Comment: You link to a post that says “Once quantization has occurred, reversing and repeating the step gives identical results. In other words, re-quantization (with the same DQT) is lossless.” You have already disproven that post. It is not true.

Comment: Yes, from a practical point of view it is not the identical result. But I really want to understand why this difference is existing in practice.